# Is there a way to connect to Microsoft SQL Server with Apache Beam?

Tags: python, sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I wanted to ask if there's a connector, function, or other that makes it posible to connect to Microsoft SQL Server tables in Apache beam, so as to write to Bigquery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Apache Beam supports [JdbcIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.html), so as long as a Dataflow Worker can reach the database and you use the right drivers for it, it should be simpler to achieve.

It is available to Python as [apache_beam.io.jdbc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.jdbc.html) and uses the expansion service, so you can get it working as long as you use [Dataflow Runner v2](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/runner-v2#python).

If you want something even simpler, you may be able to use the [JDBC to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#jdbctobigquery) Google-provided template, which is currently in beta/pre-GA.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I wanted to ask you if those templates from Google can be scheduled, with composer or something. So as to run on a periodic basis.

The reason I ask is because the pipeline I need is so basic I don't see a need to write a pipeline if there's template for it, it's just bringing a table to BigQuery. The only reason I would write the pipeline is if it's the only way to automate the MSSQL to Bigquery channel.

Comment: Yes! Please take a look at https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-dataflow-template-operator (Composer, as you asked about it) and/or https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/data-pipelines.